# How can i Bring in repeated value count to a different table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two different tables uploaded in Power BI.

Table 1:
[image]

Table 2:
[image]

I need to show the number of times the Ids in table 1 have been repeated against the ID number in the second table by creating a new column. I am fairly new to Power BI and I would love it if someone can help me out with the code.

Thanks in advance!

I am expecting something like this:
Just to be clear, i am expecting something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Establish a relationship between the tables on the `ID` column.

Add a new calculated column in `Table 2`:

```
Count = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table 1' )
)
```